# In the Next.js 13 middleware, I put a new access token as a cookie, but the page component initially shows an undefined value

Tags: next.js, next.js13

If the access token has expired through middleware.ts, a request is sent to the backend and the newly received access token value is saved as a cookie.

But the flow I think is

1. The middleware injects a new access token into a cookie.
2. Receive member information by sending the new access token within the page component.

In this flow, when first rendered within the page component, the new access token value is undefined and the member information appears only after refreshing again.

which part is wrong?

- middleware.ts code

[image]

- page.tsx

```js
export default async function Home() {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const accessTokenObj = cookieStore.get("accessToken");
  const refreshTokenObj = cookieStore.get("refreshToken");
  const accessToken = accessTokenObj?.value;

  // first rendering value is undefined
  // second rendering accessToken appears
  console.log("AccessToken Value  : ", accessToken);
```

[image]

[image]